# Windows 10 localhost: A 3rd party application hangs attempting to connect to localhost:5146, what is at this port?

Tags: windows, localhost

I downloaded and installed the Native Instruments Native Access application (context: a client app that logs on to a user account and manages licenses and installs software). It displays a logon screen then hangs. I ran ProcMon and saw that it is constantly retrying a TCP connection. I ran TCPView and found it is trying to connect to localhost:5146, which is stuck at SYN_SENT. I tried enabling Internet Information Services but the app still hangs.

Anyone have any idea what this app expects to find at localhost:5146? Crazy to have to ask this here I know but the company concerned offers zero support.